# Перевод с Delphi на C++/FASM

Tags: c++, delphi, ассемблер, fasm

Ищу перевод данной команды на язык С++ и FASM

```
DefineDosDevice(DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION,PChar(disk),nil);
```

Кто знает,напишите)

Comment: @Влад Андреев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

C++:

```
DefineDosDevice(DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION,disk,NULL);
```

Fasm:

```
DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION equ 2 ; или просто DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION = 2

invoke DefineDosDevice,DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION,disk,0
```

Comment: Зависит от типа disk. В данном случае это - LPCTSTR, см. [MSDN][1], т.е. по сути указатель на строку. Кстати, вместо NULL лучше наверное использовать null_ptr, но не уверен, что поддерживается вашим компилятором.

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363904(v=vs.85).aspx